# ng-content with dynamic transclusion

Tags: angular

I have a component containing ng-content called tabs:

```
<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

On the other hand I have...

```
<tabs>
    <tab-item *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [label]="tab.label"></tab-item>
</tabs>
```

My problem is when an item is added to tabs array, no tabs are added, I guess it comes from ng-content, but i didn't find any tips about how to trigger refresh in transclusion, is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using:  @ContentChildren(Tab) tabs: QueryList<Tab>; in your tabs component? Have a look at this: https://embed.plnkr.co/afhLA8wHw9LRnzwwTT3M/ But remember that this kind of tab will not support back button in browsers. An alternative tab is only a horizontal navigation which routes to the different pages. Which one to choose depends on the situation. A java script tab as you are doing is best to use in small details in a page. Not as a main tab page.

Comment: if your tabs come from another component, when you modify the source, need to push a notification in child component. Can use EventEmitter or a subscription.
https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: It seems to work here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uze7zv. Am I missing something?